# Trigger checkbox event automatically by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to trigger an event not manually but by jQuery itself.
Here understand my problem better:

```
$('.commonCheck').change(function () {
            if ($(".cashierCheck").attr("checked")) {
                $('.cashierInput').fadeIn();
                console.log("________________hr")
            }
            else{
                $('.cashierInput').fadeOut();
                console.log("_______________uncjecked")
            }
}
```

My checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cashierFilter" id="cashierFilter" class="cashierCheck commonCheck" class="mrL0" />
```

When I manually check/uncheck the checkbox the change event is triggered without any problem.
But I want the event to be happened when I somehow execute this:

```
$('#cashierFilter').prop('checked','true');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ga9nn/

You can use `trigger` to fire events programatically:

```
$('#cashierFilter').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

Also, you should use `is` to check the attributes of an element, and you can cache selectors in a variable to improve performance:

```
$('.commonCheck').change(function () {
    var $cashierCheck = $(".cashierCheck");
    if ($cashierCheck.is(":checked")) {
        $cashierCheck.fadeIn();
        console.log("________________hr")
    }
    else {
        $cashierCheck.fadeOut();
        console.log("_______________uncjecked")
    }
}
```

Comment: Bruvoo, added a demo, feel free to use it, sorry I touched your post yo! `:)` Woot up anyways. "demo* is with `document .ready`

Comment: @Tats_innit nice one, my brother from another mother.

Answer (score 2):

Use "is" in jquery the best solution:

```
$('.commonCheck').change(function () {
    if ($(".cashierCheck").is(":checked")) {
                $('.cashierInput').fadeIn();
                console.log("________________hr")
            }
            else{
                $('.cashierInput').fadeOut();
                console.log("_______________uncjecked")
            }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PpcLe/